# What is the efficient way of self joining date from an event stream?

Tags: sql, postgresql, etl

I'm working on an event stream for the first time so self joining a table was something that I haven't done much at large scale. I'm trying to write SQL script to give me load time of chat lobby once the user has logged in. Below I have a sample script for an ETL. I want to know if there's a better way to do joins that what I have done. I have also thought of breaking the sub queries into two separate tables and doing a left join but not sure which way is considered optimal and better practice. I also thought of doing CTE.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS event_stream;
create table event_stream
(
   event varchar(50),
   action varchar(100),
   userid int,
   session_id int,
   date timestamp
);


INSERT INTO event_stream(event, action, userid, date,session_id) VALUES
('login', 'success', 1, '2017-08-15 12:30',100),
('chatlobby','loaded', 1, '2017-08-15 12:30:10',100),
('entered_chatroom','chatroom1',1,'8/15/2017 12:31',100),
('login', 'success', 54, '2017-08-15 01:30',101),
('chatlobby','loaded', 54, '2017-08-15 01:30:05',101),
('entered_chatroom','chatroom2',54,'8/15/2017 01:31',101);

Select a.userid, a.session_id, b.date - a.date as load_time
from 
   (Select * from event_stream where event = 'login' and action='success') a
JOIN
   (Select * from event_stream where event = 'chatlobby' and action = 'loaded') b 
ON a.session_id = b.session_id
```

The script above I created was done using PostgreSQL

Comment: I am sorry if I am rude, but isn't an ETL is precisely used to replace SQL with more visual code? And by the way, what is your ETL?

Comment: Well.... yeah ETL but the company is transitioning to that infrastructure and SPARK and other tools after still being considered while we try and keep the business running as usual.

Comment: Ok, then while they are busy deciding in which direction they are going to transition, maybe you download [Kettle](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pentaho/files/Data%20Integration). It is a real ETL: is works, it is free, robust, transparent to SPARK and other data source technos, and you can copy/paste your SQL directly, so as to keep running business as usual, under the radar. Just like me. (Note: I have no commercial interest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent of your subqueries is:

```
from event_stream login join event_stream load on login.session_id = load.session.id
and login.action = 'success' 
and load.action = 'loaded'
```

This is simpler, and simplicity has its merits.  To see which way performs faster, test them.

Comment: Thanks @dan-bracuk what if I had to do group by in the sub queries because duplicate records?

Comment: That kind of changes your question.

Comment: Oh it is something I was just thinking what if that happens. What you have given as a solution is great!